# Cascading configuration in Laravel 5.1 is not working

Tags: php, laravel, configuration, environment, laravel-5.1

In Laravel 5.1 I'm trying to setup an environment specific configuration. In local and dev environment, my application(s) structure is similar to the typical subversion branches. So I have multiple installations of laravel in parallel. Example:

```
http://dev.domain/trunk/public/...
http://dev.domain/branches/branch1/public/...
```

To work with all this diffent versions of my applications I somehow need a dynamic configuration, related to the "base path", so the part between the domain and the public folder.

What I did so far, is to put the domain name in my `app.php`. What I'm struggling with, is how or where to setup, this dynamic part depend on under which subpath you're calling your application.

What I tried is to setup a config file `config/myapp/app.php`. That would be my production configuration, so the config parameter in there looks like this (Because in production I would have this subdirectories):

```
url_path_to_public = ''
```

Now I'd like to cascade this down to my local and dev environment by created a subfolder, named with my current environment `dev` and than overwrite this parameter with a dynamic expression. So this looks like:

```
'url_base_path_to_public' => strstr(str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', __FILE__), '/config/dev/myapp/app.php', true).'/public',
```

So this file is located in:

```
config/dev/myapp/app.php
```

For some reason, this parameter is not being used, even though I' running my application in `dev` mode. I expected the configuration to cascade that parameter.
The alternative would be to set this information directly in the environment-specific configuration-file `.env`, but there I cannot use a dynamic expression like that mentioned above.

Did I make any mistake with cascation to work like expected?

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 5 the cascading configuration was dropped in favour of dotenv. So the behaviour that you're expecting from setting your environment to `dev` and have it read the `config/dev/` files doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Ok, but where to put my "dynamic" path configuration?

Comment: Just found a related topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343021/laravel-5-configuration-environments-and-overriding