# Laravel 5.4 environment based config files

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am trying to change the Laravel configuration variables based on environment, but I do not know how.

Code to get config is

```
Config::get( 'contants.api_url' );
```

I am trying to have a separate results for the live environment and the development environment.

**Real life scenario**

I need to override some config files, so everybody who is using the development environment, has the same base configuration. I cannot use the .env file for this, because it is not shared between the team and everybody has their own version of it.

**What did I try:**

I read here [Laravel 5 configuration - environments and overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343021/laravel-5-configuration-environments-and-overriding) that you can create subfolders within your /config folder, that match the environment, to override the default config files. Alas it did not work for me and the Laravel 5.4 documentation on the subject matter (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#retrieving-environment-configuration) did not speak about this option, thus I believe it might have been deprecated.

Comment: What are the config values you want to change?

Comment: Let's say config/constants.php file has a value api_url, which I need to override for everyone on the development server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to use a service provider. If you're only going to be overriding one or two values then you might as well just use your `AppServiceProvider`, otherwise I would suggest creating a new service (e.g. `ConfigServiceProvider`).

In the `boot()` method of your service provider you could add something like:

```
if (app()->environment() === 'local') {
   config()->set('contants.api_url', 'http://example.com');
}
```

Comment: I upvoted, but I do not particularly like the design of this approach. Are you sure Laravel has no core functionality akin to this? https://github.com/machaven/laravel-cascading-config. If not, then I will mark it as an answer..

Comment: @FifthEon No, I don't believe Laravel has this functionality anymore but I could be mistaken. To be fair, the github repo you mentioned above is a very similar approach to what I've suggested. With the example you gave in your comment I assumed you were only going to be changing one or two values so I didn't really see the point in showing a more elaborate system but if you look at the repo it's only really providing a service provider https://github.com/machaven/laravel-cascading-config/blob/master/src/CascadingConfigProvider.php which again checks the env and replaces the config values.

Comment: thats true, I just don't like the idea of incorporating non-scalable solutions into our big application. But again, it's probably only going to be a few variables yes, so I will use that.

Answer (score 1):

To change the configuration variables based on environment, this will do:

*Example file:* **config/database.php**

```
       'mysql' => [
            'driver' => mysql,
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host'=> (env('APP_ENV') === 'local' ? env('DB_HOST_LOCAL') : env('DB_HOST_PRODUCTION')),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'default'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'options' => (env('APP_ENV') === 'local' ? [
                'some_option' =>  env('SOME_ENV')
            ] : []),
        ],
```

Tested and works on Laravel 5.8.